# google spreadsheets - ajax call (get and post)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-docs

what I need to do is read the content of a "public" google spreadsheet (by public I mean that I saved the sheet clicking on "File > Publish to the web", so it's accessible without the need to be logged in into a google account), and, why not, write something into it too.

googlin' around, I found that I can access the sheet and get the xml equivalent of the sheet content with something like

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/<sheetCode>/od6/public/values
```

It works great if I load that url into a browser. But I need to find a "javascript-way" to get and handle the returned value, ie the xml (or json, but xml would be preferable).

I tried to use an ajax call, but I think there's something messy with the protocol.. I can't get the server response correctly.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/<sheetCode>/od6/public/values",
    success: function(data){alert("yeah");},
    error: function(){alert("fail..");},
    dataType:"xml",
});
```

I also tried to get the json instead of xml, adding "?alt=json" to the url and changing the datatype, but I still have the problem..

Any idea / suggestion?

Thanks in advance, best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to request with a JSONP call and you need to specifiy a callback - method. This can be done in jQuery using:

```
var url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/<CODE>/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=?';
jQuery.getJSON(url).success(function(data) {
    console.log(data); 
}).error(function(message) {
    console.error('error' + message); 
}).complete(function() {
    console.log('completed!'); 
});
```

Documentation and samples for [google spreedsheets](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample) .

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed the jsonp part! the callback function doesn't work, using "?alt=json" inside the URL instead of "alt=json-in-script&callback=something" I can get the json properly. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-get-data-from-google-spreadsheet-json

Comment: This API is out of date (deprecated)